# Admin Management User devise routing ruby on rails example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise, model, routes

Lets say I have 3 devise models (admin, management,user) and I have article model

I want to create url (routing) in this way:

- for devise models

  localhost/admin

  localhost/management

  localhost/user
- for articles for the particular devise user

  localhost/admin/articles (articles by admin)

  localhost/management/articles (articles by management)

  localhost/user/articles (articles by user)

Can someone create a simple sample or guide me on how to configure such setup on ruby on rails ?

I'ved created a git with the initial code. can you contribute this issue into this git sample ?
https://github.com/axilaris/admin_user_devise_articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use namespaces. There is a good description in the Rails routing guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You can also force authentication in a said namespace by adding `authenticate` as follows:

```
namespace :admin do
  authenticate :admin do
    resources :articles, only: :index
  end
end
```

Finally, you can specify the devise after sign in and/or sign out path adding the following to `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    user_articles_path # or whatever path you want
  elsif resource.is_a?(Admin)
    ...
  elsif resource.is_a?(Management)
    ...
  end
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  new_session_path(resource) # or whatever path you want
end
```

Comment: still not sure how its done, i'ved added this branch test_namespace_branch in https://github.com/axilaris/admin_user_devise_articles. "uninitialized constant Admin::ArticlesController" when i go into http://localhost:3000/admin/articles

Comment: You need to add some articles controller in the admin namespace. I'll take a quick look at your git...

Comment: i'ved got something working. checkout master. i created the articles_controller.rb under admin and user. https://github.com/axilaris/admin_user_devise_articles/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/articles_controller.rb. works now with localhost:3000/admin/articles. now trying to get authentication working.

Comment: I cloned your repo. Yes, that looks correct to me. Good job.

Comment: Thanks. However I cannot get devise working properly. http://localhost:3000/admins/sign_in complains "Cannot redirect to nil!". Also, how do i secure localhost:3000/admin/articles with "admin" model authentication only and not user.

Comment: ok its because of elsif resource.is_a?(Admin). updated in master.

Comment: now the problem is /admin/sign_in or /admin/sign_out ---redirects--> to /admin/articles. how can i get it to authenticate first before redirecting. and how can i make sure /admin/articles is protected by admin model ? Thanks hope you dont mine. trying to get this small little example thing to work properly.

Comment: When you go to `/admin/articles`, it should show the sign in page if not signed in. After sign out, you can control the path adding to `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: ok solve it. i'ved added in dashboard as well. thanks a whole lot for your help! btw, can you help also to differentiate the login views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003360/different-view-for-devise-sign-in-sign-out-for-2-authentication-model-user-a ?

Comment: Glad I could help.