# Different View for Devise sign_in/sign_out for 2 authentication model - User & Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, view, devise, model

I have made this simple test app that have 2 different authentication model
- User
- Admin
https://github.com/axilaris/admin_user_devise_articles

I want to have different view layouts for User and Admin for devise. How can I customize this.

For example:

```
localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

should be different than

```
localhost:3000/admins/sign_in
```

Please feel free to modify my github repo to have this different sign_in/sign_up views. Thanks.

Comment: Did you see how you can generate devise views and then edit them in devise wiki on github? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Comment: You may want to override the devise default controller and views to achieve that, and then in your routes specify the correct controller to use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in application controoler I added a method called after_sign_in_path_for which checks role and redirect to required view
here is a method

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.has_role? :admin
      users_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Basically Deep has the answer, its in here:

github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

do this:

rails generate devise:views users

set:

config.scoped_views = true inside the config/initializers/devise.rb file.

updating the git repo to reflect this feature. thanks @Deep